# "new document button" disappear on Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a simple documents list on my web Site.
When I access it with my browser (IE or Chrome, doesn't matter), the "new button" to create document appears and just after 0.5 seconds, disappears (and not presents in DOM HTML page !)
This effect occurs on "modern experience", in "classical experience", I have the "new button"

I am sure I had this button last week ... I change something somewhere, but I don't what ? or I have un bug somewhere

Do you have any ideas to help me ???

Thanks a lot for your help

Best regards :)

PS1 : I saw`enter code here` this post  : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Doc-Library-webpart-quot-New-quot-button-missing/m-p/224635 and try to change the params about "client application" against "web app application" , but it is not a solution ... :|

PS2 : I try to "manage contents" or "not" for this "Documents List", but nothing changes too ... :|

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: thank for your help, I have an another Library on this site, and all work fine ... I am sure I change someting somewhere, but "what" ? I will compare each properties today and give you a feedback ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue if I edit new menu and uncheck all the options.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can click on Upload>Template>upload the template file to enable the New option and then click on Edit New menu> enable all content types to see the result.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: WONDERFUL !!!! Thanks a lot !!!! it's work fine now :)

Comment: it was works fine ... snif ... :( ...

A) I downloaded a new model and I recovered my new button and menu under it, with your tip !

B) but after, I unchecked this new model ...

Now, New button dissappears again, but Download button don't show "Template" Item choice ... 

I think I have decorelation between checked model type  and accessible model type ...

(PS : I did A) and B) step Two time : the first time, "Download Template Item" re-appears ..., but not the second time ...

I'am very sorry ...

Comment: Per my test, I could not reproduce your issue. The "Template" choice is always in the Upload button.

Comment: I don't known why but the "Template" Button came back this morning ...
May be an explanation : my Library is visible in a specific page (Default page of my web site) with a webPart and in the default aspx page of the list : the "Template" button is visible only in the second page ... yesterday, may be, I am concentrate on the first web page and not the second ...

Comment: Please accept it as answer if it helps you.

Comment: It is an awswer, thanks, my question is closed ... but I don't know how I will able to close it ... I hope this comment is enought